# will or be going to after "believe"?

Tags: difference

I don't know which sentence is true and I need some help.

> I believe that the faculty members **will** be very useful for my future studies.

or

> I believe that the faculty members **are going to** be very useful for my future studies.

Comment: The use of "believe" doesn't change the general answer.  In short, you can use either.  Will" is the most neutral way to talk about future events.  "Going to" is sometimes preferred when talking about future events that result from the current situation.  "Will" is also a little more formal.  But in this situation, you can pick either.

Comment: What @JamesK said. Putting the words ***I believe that*** at the front of any assertion makes absolutely no difference to syntax of the assertion that follows/

Answer (score 1):

It should be faculty *memberships* rather than faculty members, as you are going to make use of the memberships rather than your fellow members.

'will' and 'be going to' have very slight different meanings, but both could be used here, depending on your intentions.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will

> Be going to or will?
> Will is often used in a similar way to be going to. Will is used when we are talking about something with absolute certainty. Be going to is used when we want to emphasise our decision or the evidence in the present: …

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work

> Predictions

> We use be going to to predict something that we think is certain to happen or which we have evidence for now:

> It’s going to snow again soon. (The speaker can probably see dark snow clouds.)

Comment: I don't understand your comment "It should be faculty memberships rather than faculty members."  Why couldn't the members themselves be useful?  Also, *memberships* sounds like the speaker is the member of more than one faculty at a time, which would be odd.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine.

I also think "faculty members" makes much more sense than "faculty memberships."